# Black bird wreaks havoc

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I once read a truly scary short story: a bird sits in a cage. Out of the sky comes a huge, dark bird. It enters the cage and after a few days(weeks?) the bird in the cage hatches a kind of monster bird, and dies. Now awful things happen in the formerly peaceful little town. People start lying about their neighbours and murder happens. In the end the bird breaks his cage, spreads his wings and flies to another town, so the reader could imagine what would start to happen there.

I read this story almost 40 years ago, in a collection of short ghost stories. I had rented the book in the Public Library, Cambridge MA. I remember two other stories: Afterward and Rip van Winkle.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This sounds interesting, but it's a bit thin on details.  If you check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) they might help you recall some additional details to [edit] into the question.  For example, when and where did you read this?

Comment: I read this story almost 40 years ago. The story was in a collection of short ghost stories. I had rented the book in the Public Library, Cambridge MA. I remember two other stories: Afterward and Rip van Winkle.

Comment: @Allegra the story *Afterward* by Edith Wharton?

Comment: @Allegra  Do you mean the huge, dark bird comes from heaven  or from the sky?  It seems to me that a bird with evil offspring would more likely come from hell than from heaven.  Ha! Ha!

Comment: @JohnRennie Those old public domain stories have been anthologized a _lot_ but I can't find any overlap between "Afterward" and "Rip van Winkle"...

Comment: @Allegra Are you sure you meant *Rip Van Winkle* (which isn't a ghost story) and not another well known story by Washington Irving *The Legend of Sleepy Hollow*?  Those two stories have been anthologised together.

Comment: Please excuse me, English is not my mother tongue. Of course the bird came from the sky, not from heaven.At the end of the story it flew to another town, so the reader could imagine what would start to happen there. - It was Rip van Winkle, I am quite sure of that. Many years later I read Needful Things by Stephen King. That story made me remember the Bird Sstory.

Comment: John Rennie, yes, I think it was Afterward by Edith Wharton. Someone paid a visit; only when he had left people came to realize it had been a ghost. A very well written story.

Comment: I found a book called "Representative Modern Short Stories" (ed Alexander Jessup, 1929) that contains both "Afterward" and "Rip Van Winkle". See if your story is in it. https://archive.org/stream/representativemo001704mbp/representativemo001704mbp_djvu.txt

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help me!

Comment: Moriarty, the story I try to find is not in the book, but it contains many other interesting stories. Thank you for your information.